# Can any one experience the World without a language? if yes to what extent, if no, why not?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, language

By listening, speaking, seeing and reflecting on words made by the alphabets of a language - one experiences the World. How far is this correct? Can any one experience the World without a language? if yes to what extent, if no, why not?

Comment: Babies experience the world without a language. Also see this [thread](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/do-people-think-in-a-language) on Skeptics.

Comment: Thats correct !! that experience is not sharable unless they learn a language alphabet to express ! It will be interesting to explore more on the bias that Language introduces to the babies to share their experience on one hand - as per the codes/rules/structures learnt for a language , and on the other hand even that experience sharing would not have been possible without language tools. So the True experience of Babies' enters into a bias with the language and becomes unsharable without a language

Comment: Heidegger's lecture series, 'The Fundamental Concepts of Metaphysics', is a thorough examination of the man vs. animal relation to the world, which to me seems very relevant to the question. For a shorter (and more crude) overview, Agamben's 'The Open' is also rather interesting.

Comment: @Dzmitry - Thanks a lot, I will greatly appreciate more inputs on what current research directs one to, in terms of USING the tools of a language (any of the known languages) evolved / developed experiencing what was before the origin of a language or what world is experienceable without the language, what is that connects the before-in-between(link/connection/that transforms)-with the tools of a language  and then sharing that experience using these known tools of a language.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, sorry for bad English!
I can't answer by all means but here are two points.

- It is well known that children, that *grow up* without a language,
  get a fatal lack of human consciousness.
- Buddhists assert that *adult human* beigns may (and should) spend a long time without
  words and estimations and this even improve their minds.
  I practise Vipassana more than 15 years (being high-educated in theoretical physics)
  and just confirm it.

Comment: point 1 - it seems to some extent the children/ or we as human get their/our consciousness eclipsed with the language tools and same tools - we need to experience the world also. Certainly !! agree on point 2

Answer (score 1):

How else would you experience the world? Is the color red itself the same as the word 'red'?

Of course we use words to *describe* our experience to others.

One could examine the world out there as *logos* by Christianity, a *system of signs* by semiotics in European philosohy as inspired by linguistics or *information* as modern physics - but this is language of an entirely different order and amongst themselves are not commensurate. In this sense no-one escapes language in their structuring of experience.

Comment: Thanks, if not with a language how would one experience the world !! Exactly ! Now let's go a step further, having learnt the language - can it help narrating, recalling the experience Patricia Kuhl(TedTalks)refers Neuroscience may term as Rocket Science or romantic poets term it as -Celestial Openness of Child's mind before formally learning a langauge. Having the tools of a Language can one experience the world that was before the language was learn, if so, how? So What that LANGUAGE would be, as I agree with you again, "no-one escapes language in ..";Much appreciated.